# VueRouter wait for ajax is done

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-resource

I am building SPA and the problem is checking if user is admin or not.

After `Vue.auth.getUserInfo()` I want to stop whole application and wait for API response, `Vue.auth.user.isAdmin` is always false because I don't have response from api...

Here is router.beforeEach

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

   if(Vue.auth.user.authenticated == false) {
       Vue.auth.getUserInfo();
   }

   if(Vue.auth.user.isAdmin) {
      next({ name: 'admin.index' })
   } else {
      next({name: 'client.index'})
   }
}
```

Get user info method:

```
getUserInfo() {
    Vue.http.get('/api/me')
        .then(({data}) => {
            this.user = data;
        }, () => {
            this.logout();
        })
}
```

Comment: that's a shame that you missed my answer because it was posted minute earlier and went down...

Comment: No, dude sorry but your answer is not complete because what happens if user is authenticated? Your answer is correct but its missing one small part of code, I really appreciate that you tried to helped me. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the state of `Vue.auth.user.isAdmin` is managed within your `Vue.auth.getUserInfo()` logic, you can try a promise approach (untested):

```
getUserInfo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Vue.http.get('/api/me')
      .then(({data}) => {
        this.user = data;
        // Or, to use when consuming this within the then() method:
        resolve(data);
      }, () => {
        reject();
      })
  })
}
```

Then, when you consume it in your guard (https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html):

```
// A couple small auth/guard helper functions
function guardCheck(next) {
  if(Vue.auth.user.isAdmin) {
    next({ name: 'admin.index' })
  } else {
    next({name: 'client.index'})
  }
}
function guardLogout(next) {
  Vue.auth.user.logout()
    .then(() => {
      next({ name: 'home.index', params: { logout: success }})
    })
}

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(Vue.auth.user.authenticated === false && !to.matched.some(record => record.meta.isGuest)) {
    Vue.auth.getUserInfo()
      .then((user) => {
        guardCheck(next)
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // Not sure how your logout logic works but maybe...
        guardLogout(next)
      })
  } else {
     guardCheck(next)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It  is asynchronus request.

You have few options.
1. Move this function to vue-router and place your code:

```
   if(Vue.auth.user.authenticated == false) {
       Vue.auth.getUserInfo();
   }

   if(Vue.auth.user.isAdmin) {
      next({ name: 'admin.index' })
   } else {
      next({name: 'client.index'})
   }
}
```

in `then()` function of your request.

2. Probably better for your learning curve - to modify your `getUserInfo()` to be promise based.

You will then have in your `auth` module something like:

```
var getUserInfo = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
 Vue.http.get('/api/me')
        .then(({data}) => {
            this.user = data;
            resolve();
        }, () => {
            this.logout()
            reject();
        })
}
```

and in your router:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

   if(Vue.auth.user.authenticated == false) {
       Vue.auth.getUserInfo().then(()=>{
if(Vue.auth.user.isAdmin) {
      next({ name: 'admin.index' })
   } else {
      next({name: 'client.index'})
   }
});
   }


}
```

I don't have an editor with me so it can have some small issues but generally should work. Hope it helps!